Relating animal sightings with land cover - poisson, negative binomial, zero inflated and then LOST
I have a number of sightings of animals in a location (an island). The sightings are opportunistic (corpses people stumble upon) and happen in different land covers. I am supposed to investigate if there is a link between a land cover and the chances of finding a dead animal (just to see if there are some strange things happening, such as finding more fish on the road instead in a lake). So just to see if my data makes sense or the process of collecting/sampling these animals was so bad that we can't use it to infer anything about the habitat's importance for the animal.
I have 145 locations, all the same size. For each location I have a n(animal sightings) and % of each land cover for each location.
My knowledge of stats is budding, and I am an enthusiast, but feel free to rip me apart (just use the terms I will understand).
The count data says Poisson, the distribution resembles Poisson, I do a one-sample K-S test and the distribution is not significantly different from Poisson. There is no multicollinearity between the predictor variables. I check mean vs. variance, too different (1.02 vs 1.8). Poisson regression confirms it (value/df=1.459). So I consult literature, which says do a negative binomial, but check for zeroes beforehand. Indeed out of 145 units of analysis, 80 are zero sightings. I don't know which ones are true zeroes and which excess zeroes. Should I just abandon the idea of doing a negative binomial? Is there an easier way to do this? As I am not confident (knowledgeable enough) to deal with these zeroes. Are they even relevant? Many thanks.

Might I suggest thinking first, and very hard, about what question(s) you might be able to answer?  For instance, your problem formulation appears to be inconsistent.  The "chances of finding a dead animal" depend on the rates at which animals visit each area, their rates of death in those areas, the frequencies with which those areas are visited by people, and the chance that a human visitor will detect a corpse.  However, not all these factors are indicators of "strange things happening:" that's the apparent inconsistency.  What, then, is it that you really need to investigate?

Agreed, however I don't have access to any of these variables. This is a part of a larger project dealing with animal population genetics, and I am trying to see if there's a way to suggest that these carcasses (opportunistic sampling, no way around it!) are at least found in places where you'd more or less expect them (or at least that the sample we have isn't found in really weird places, e.g. squirrels found mostly in swamps and beaches), which would mean that the sample is bad from an ecological point of view (not saying this proves otherwise). Or I might just be talking out of my a*s.

A couple things to help you out. @whuber's comment is a good one but assuming this is all the data you have we can assume your analytic task is to "determine whether there is a relationship between land cover and number of animal sightings (ignoring everything else)" and move on.
First, the distribution of $Y$ (number of sightings) is likely different than the distribution of $Y | X$ ($X$ being land cover). The distribution of $Y | X$ is what you are modeling, not $Y$. If $Y$ was actually Poisson, then $Y | X$ would be some sort of underdispersed count variable, because $Y$ is generally more variable than $Y|X$, due to the variation in $X$. If your variable is actually underdispersed, there are not many distributions available(the double Poisson is one).
But you said the sample variance of $Y$ is greater than the sample mean of $Y$, so it is completely plausible that $Y|X$ is actually Poisson or perhaps even negative binomial. Note that the negative binomial generalizes Poisson with an additional spread parameter, so a negative binomial regression will always fit at least as well on the input data as a Poisson regression would. You can try a negative binomial regression and always revert to a Poisson if the spread parameter in the negative binomial is extreme (either very close to 0 or very large, depending on the software's parameterization).
As for the zero-inflation problem, from your post it sounds like the fitted values in the regression ($E(Y|X)$) are very small, meaning that it is natural to expect a lot of "true" zeros. In general I would assume that the zeros you observe are true zeros unless you have reason to assume that there is some phenomenon that would drive excess zeros (e.g. a data entry or censoring issue). But just like negative binomial vs. Poisson, zero-inflated distributions generalize their non-inflated equivalents. So you could always try to fit a zero-inflated model and revert to the non-inflated model if the returned probability of an excess 0 was very close to 0.

Thanks for this, it is appreciated. I did some more reading, it seems that in ecology excess zeroes are quite normal, and I suspect a lot of my zeroes are such. I've tried fitting Poisson, NB and ZINB, and despite the assumption that a lot of zeroes are excess, the ZINB didn't do a better job, as there are probably many more variables that are playing a role here (which I don't have access to). Then I did some more reading, and it seems that the "new" thing in spatial ecological modelling are hierarchical models. Now I have to spend a lot of time trying to wrap my head around it!
